# Hierarchical dependency resolutions in inheritance c#

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, architecture

To maintain the separation of concern, I am trying to create the layered project architecture. lets consider below example.

- `ProjectA` is `class library` and has

  - interface `IntefaceA`
  - Abstract Class `ClassA` implements `InterfaceA`
- `ProjectB` is `class library` and reference `ProjectA` and has

  - Abstract Class `ClassB` inherit `ClassA` ( PrjectA reference added in ProjectB )
- `ProjectC` has

  - Class `ClassC` which inherited from `ClassB` so added `ProjectB` as reference in `ProjectC`

Now issue is, in `ProjectC` I am getting error `The type ClassA is defined in an assembly that is not referenced`

Questions is

1. Why `ProjectC` need `ProjectA` reference
2. Do I need to add all the `referenced project` all way to the hierarchical chain
3. How can I achieve separated design while reducing the dependency

Comment: Since `ClassB` *is an* instance of `ClassA`, any code which uses `ClassB` will need to be aware of `ClassA`.  So, yes, a reference to that project would be required.  This doesn't really break your structure because that dependency is already there because of the dependency that `ProjectB` already has on `ProjectA`.  As for your last question, it's not really clear what you're trying to achieve here.  You can't separate things which directly depend on each other, those things would still need to reference each other.

Comment: *"Why ProjectC need ProjectA reference"* -- because ProjectC uses types defined in ProjectA. Is there really a question here? You clearly understand what the problem is and how to fix it. I don't blame you for not liking it, but it is what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a commonly complained about feature of the visual studio compiler. It will only build out and link assemblies that are referenced directly in the project, it doesn't iterate through the hierarchy.

If ClassC has a direct dependency on code in Project A, it needs to reference ProjectA to compile correctly.

You don't need to include the entire hierarchy in every project, just what it references. If Project B references Project X, Y, and Z for other things, but Project C doesn't derived from anything from Project B that uses them, then Project C doesn't need a reference.

One way to keep things separate and reduce direct dependencies like this is to use dependency injection frameworks. MEF is such an example.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/mef/

In this case, where you are directly deriving from a class that directly derives from anther class in another assembly, you are basically stuck referencing that assembly, since the compiler requires it to properly compile your ClassC, and isn't designed to iterate through the dependency hierarchy.